# how to make file open in specific mobile app from anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file that I want to host it and make it open with a specific app once I click a button or anchor element (`<a></a>`). So in other words instead of downloading the file.abc then clicking on that file -> open with... -> app that runs .abc files, I want that to happen directly when the link or button is clicked is that possible (I only care about it on mobile).

Comment: "Deep linking" is what this is referred to. And I think you, as the host of the file, cannot control that. The app that you want to be able to open `.abc` files would need to register with the OS that it can handle `.abc` files and require the user to set that as the default app to open `.abc` files. See https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking for more info for android, https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/ for ios.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones thank you for the reply, the idea is that I have a sticker pack (.wastickers file) generated by the app from this website [link](https://getstickerpack.com/) so from mobile phones it asks user to open inside the app if it's available if not it redirects to the store, the idea is that this works with their hosted packs but not with the custom one I made so am trying to find a workaround